# nodeschool javascripting ARRAY FILTERING

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var filtered = numbers.filter(function evenNumbers (number) {
  return number % 2 === 0;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

I am total beginner to JavaScript, picking up the course offered by nodeschool. While in the exercise of "ARRAY FILTERING", I wonder what is the role of 'number' within the function evenNumbers as it was not declared beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* declared, as a formal parameter to the callback `evenNumbers` (a function that takes an argument and tests whether it is even). `filter` will call the callback function once for each element of the array `numbers`, providing the element as the argument to the callback (which will assign it to `number`, via the usual function invocation process).

Comment: So that means 'number' in the function representing the arrays within the 'numbers', which declared in the very beginning, and the function is filtering the numbers based on 'evenNumbers'? @Amadan

Comment: `evenNumbers` is the criterion for `filter`. You ask `evenNumbers(1)`, it says `false`. `evenNumbers(2)`, and it says `true`. `filter` will append each element to the result or not depening on what the callback function says; so `1` is not appended, and `2` is appended. Thus, the result ends up `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` with `1`, `3`, `5`, `7` and `9` missing.

Answer (score 0):

1. `numbers` is an Array
2. `.filter` is a method declared on `Array.prototype`
3. `.filter` method accepts a `callback function`.
4. Internally it looks Like,

,

```
Array.prototype.filter(callback[, thisArgs]) {
    '''''
    '''''
    callback(currentElement, index, arrayObjectBeingTraversed)
});
```

So,

In your case,

```
callback  --> function evenNumbers() {}

currentElement --> Number
```

### <kbd>[More about Javascript Callback Functions](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/)</kbd>